# Add printer Windows 8 programmatically

Tags: windows, printing, cmd, inno-setup, rundll32

I am working on a Virtual Printer and I'm stuck at printer installation. Installation is made by InnoSetup

```
[run] Filename : rundll32.exe; Parameters: "printui.dll, PrintUIEntry /if /f ""{app}\ghostscript\ghostpdf.inf"" /r ""TitusVirtualPrinter:"" /m ""Ghostscript PDF"" /b ""Virtual Printer""  /u /Y "; StatusMsg: Installing PS Printer for Ghostscript; Description: Ghostscript PS Printer; Flags: waituntilterminated shellexec;
```

That line works perfectly and the program installs on Windows 7 systems (Pro 32&64bits) but not in Windows 8. I don't have any error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could it be the same as this:

http://www.jenovarain.com/2012/12/ghostscript-printer-on-windows-8-64-bit/

perhaps they key information in that article relating to your problem is

> you will want to select option #7 “Disable Driver Signature
>   Enforcement”